# Updating data based on latest date/time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has 1 weeks data but I need to add additional data from the source table based on the latest date/time entry in a field called SDT_G

So for example if my table has a max date/time of 22/08/2018 23:56:32 I want to insert data from the source table with a date/time greater than that.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: did you try using a "where" clause in your query that fetches the data? E.g. where date > '22/08/2018 23:56:32'

Comment: Sample data and desired results (probably simplified) would really help other people understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are thinking?

```
insert into dest_table (col1, col2, . . .)
    select s.col1, s.col2, . . .
    from source_table s
    where s.datecol > (select max(d.datecol) from dest_table);
```

Comment: @Y.S . . . If you want clarification from the OP, the appropriate think to do is to *ask* the OP.  Downvoting a probably-correct answer is rude in my book.

Comment: Thanks, that looks to do exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What more info do you need given that what was provided originally was sufficient for someone to answer the question?